# Flash Professional can't find Flex SDK

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I've tried using an [Embed] tag in my flash ActionScript file for the first time.

```
[Embed (source="../art/room.dae", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
```

When I tried to run, Flash posted a warning:

[image: warning]
I downloaded the latest Flex SDK from adobe and pointed the path there, but it still has no effect.  I then did some searching which said I should just press the Update Library Path button and everything would work, but this is having no effect for me.  (Although I'm not entirely sure that the path I'm using is the correct one - I didn't write it down before trying the downloaded SDK).

Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: Re-check your path.  This is almost certainly because you're using an incorrect path.

Comment: Use that "folder" icon to navigate to and select where you stored the SDK. Also, if yu downloaded the latest (from Adobe) that is 4.6. Your path is pointing to 4.5

Comment: Does look like a warning you would get from Flash IDE not from Flash Builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try installing a Flex SDK by using the very comfortable [Apache Flex SDK Installer](http://flex.apache.org/installer.html).

However usually Flash Builder or Flash Develop are used to develop Flex applications (in ActionScript and MXML) - and not Flash Professional IDE.

If you try to use Flex components from Flash Professional IDE - most likely they won't work.